# Page Jump Issue cant launch website till fixed

Tags: html, css

im nearly ready to launch my website but i have a problem i cannot sort out.
ive built the whole website using wordpress and buddypress.

due to the picture in my header being very big and ending 450px down the page, you have to scroll down to access the buddypress menu in the relevant page (the one above the activity stream etc) which is exactly where i want it, removing my header is not an option, now the only problem i am having is that when i click the tabs in the buddypress menu say from activity stream to say my messages instead of the page laoding and taking me back to this section it takes me to the very top of my header so i have to re-scroll back down to the page i was after.

I need the page to stay at the same point after page reload so that the menus can be flicked through without having to scroll down to it again everytime a link is pressed. how do i achieve this? can you please help me sort this out….i have no problems adding or editing codes if i know what code needs changing and what to add to make it do this. thx

Comment: by the way i cannot remove this header from said pages as it is a unique feature in my site...ive made the main nav bar fit into my header for navigation to the rest of my content in such a way the header looks like it is the navigation.....its only the buddypress menu i need to stay in position on page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that if you look in the url bar it is adding a # to the end of the url.  You need to override the default click event on the a tag so that it doesnt jump you to the top.  Im not sure how that will affect the stuff that is going on in the BuddyPress plugin.

Comment: Hi Cwitty thx for your reply...no there is no # appearing in the url of each navigation link...im really getting desperate to fix this to work how i need it to,this website is a 3 month project that has took me on average 12 hours a day solid....i cannot back out now at the final hurdles...this is the first time ive ever built a website from scratch...ive learned alot on this 3 month journey of madness, but when it comes to the buddypress plugin im lost as i cannot for the life of me find the files where the buddypress menu links are stored to change them even if they did have a # in the link.

Comment: i have searched and searched the net and have stumbled on a page with some code thats called scroll sneak [link](http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/) any ideas how i would use this for my buddypress menu? im unclear where i would put the codes in my website? if i put the code in my header.php file etc how do i find the where the links on the buddypress menu are and what code would i add to them to make them execute scroll sneak on said link?  could anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: @pokernut can you send a link to your site so I can inspect what is going on?